# Validity of ternary expression

Tags: awk

I am setting the variable `hit` according to whether `impl == "MATCH"`.  Whilst most do suggest trying things out to confirm the execution of the code, this question is primarily intended for others to see whether there could be side-effects or poor coding style, so that I improve it.

```
  (impl == "MATCH") ? hit = $0 ~ prl : hit = match($0, prl)
```

Comment: Is your `awk` able to use it? If no, what is the error message? If yes, good, but you may still want to clarify your question. In the end, it depends on what your intent is.

Comment: `hit = $0 ~ prl` and `hit = match($0, prl)` will populate `hit` identically so there is no point of that ternary expression choosing between them vs only doing `hit = $0 ~ prl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to write this,

```
if (impl == "MATCH") { hit = ($0 ~ prl) } else { hit = match($0, prl) }
```

If so, then since both result parts are an assignment to the same variable, you could write it like this,

```
hit = (impl == "MATCH") ? ($0 ~ prl) : match($0, prl)
```

Your own code does work (did you try it?), but it's not really using the ternary operator in an expression; instead it's more a convoluted `if`…`then`…`else` construct that uses a side-effect to drive the primary intention of assignment. I'd call this poor coding style.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do what you described.  Whilst most do suggest trying to see if things word, the intention was primarily about others detecting possible side-effects and poor coding style, so that I can do things better.

Comment: @Enver We can't see into your thoughts. If you wanted suggestions on your coding style, this should have been part of the question. As it stands, you appear to ask a simple syntax question that is trivial to answer by testing the code in a program.

Comment: There are also other sites to request code review rather than help solving a problem.